# Php email script not sending the email

Tags: php

I'm running apache server on my localhost and I'm trying to send an email from the php script but it doesn't work , I've never received the emails.

This is the default example from php :

```
<?php
$to      = 'emailaddress@yahoo.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: myemail@yahoo.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: myemail@yahoo.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Where's the issue?

Comment: Do you also have a mailserver running on your localhost? What's the return value from `mail()`?

Comment: if you have a mailserver running what does the log of it say?

Comment: I dont have a mailserver running , just apache and php are installed on the machine.

Comment: Then how do you expect this to work? Install XAMPP which comes with Mercury (local email server) to try out your emails.

Comment: Can I do this using hMailServer software?

Comment: Look at PHPMailer : https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: Do you check SPAM folder?

Comment: Check what is return mail function var_dump(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))

Answer (score 0):

*Reference: Comment section of the question*

You are actually not having an email server set up in the environment you're working on, that why the emails are not being sent.

The `mail` function returns `false` if the email failed to be sent and you should perform a check and see what the function call returns:

```
$mail = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

if (!$mail)
{
    do_something();
}
```

To set up an email server on your localvhost you could use [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html) for Windows which comes with *Mercury Mail*; a tool that enables emails in your local environment.

There are different approaches to setting up a mail server locally, but this is the one I'm familiar with. A simple Google search would do.